# VIPER architecture using Swift to store data in presenter

Tags: swift, architecture

So I'm setting up a simple VIPER architecture in Swift.

The Interactor gets some data from an API, and passes the data to the presenter that then passes formatted data to the view.

The presenter will process the data, and just count the number of objects that are downloaded. To do so I have stored a var in the presenter. The question is should I store data in the presenter?

Interactor:

```
class Interactor {
weak var presenter: Presenter?

    func getData() {
        ClosureDataManager.shared.fetchBreaches(withURLString: baseUrl + breachesExtensionURL, completion: { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let breaches):
                self.presenter?.dataDidFetch(breaches: breaches)
                self.presenter?.dataNumberDidFetch(number: breaches.count)
            }

        })
    }

}
```

Presenter:

```
class Presenter {

    var wireframe: Wireframe?
    var view: ViewController?
    var interactor: Interactor?

    var dataDownloaded = 0

    func viewDidLoad() {
        print ("presenter vdl")
    }

    func loadData() {
        interactor?.getData()
    }

    func dataDidFetch(breaches: [BreachModel]) {
        view?.dataReady()
    }

    func showDetail(with text: String, from view: UIViewController) {
        wireframe?.pushToDetail(with: text, from: view)
    }

    func dataNumberDidFetch(number: Int) {
        dataDownloaded += number
        view?.showData(number: String(dataDownloaded) )
    }

}
```

View (ViewController)

```
protocol dataViewProtocol {
    func showData(number: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, dataViewProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var showDetailButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!

// weak here means it won't work
var presenter: Presenter?

@IBAction func buttonPressAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    presenter?.loadData()
}

@IBAction func buttonShowDetailAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    presenter?.showDetail(with: "AAA", from: self)
}

func dataReady() {
    showDetailButton.isEnabled = true
}

func showData(number: String) {
    dataLabel.text = number
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Wireframe.createViewModule(view: self)
    presenter?.viewDidLoad()
}

}
```

Router (Wireframe)

```
class Wireframe {

    static func createViewModule (view: ViewController) {
        let presenterInst = Presenter()
        view.presenter = presenterInst
        view.presenter?.wireframe = Wireframe()
        view.presenter?.view = view
        view.presenter?.interactor = Interactor()
        view.presenter?.interactor?.presenter = presenterInst

    }
}
```

So should the presenter be used to store the number of objects downloaded?

**What have you tried** I've implemented the var, as shown above. This is a minimum example of the problem.

**What resources have you used** I've looked on StackOverflow, and Googled the issue. I can't find an answer, but know I could store the data in the view but I think this is incorrect. I could store the number of data in the Interactor, but this also doesn't seem right. It all seems...to violate separation of concerns...

**I won't do your homework / use a different architecture / You should use protocols / Why is there a single protocol in your implementation** This isn't homework, it is for my own self - study. There may be other architectures that can be used to do this (and coding to protocols is good practice) but this is about storing a variable in the presenter. I want to know if I should store the variable in the presenter, using VIPER and using Swift. Comments about trivia around the question are seldom helpful if they are about variable names, or the like.

**What is the question?** I want to know if I can store the number of downloaded data items in the presenter.

Comment: I think it's not a problem to store data in the presenter if data itself is needed only to be shown in the view. Let's say I fetch a list of recipes from API: the interactor gives the presenter the array of recipes, the presenter stores and tells the view to update and show that list. Then, if the view has a table view and I want to do stuff on row selected, the view will tell the presenter that a row has been selected at a certain index; the presenter will easily know which recipes is at that index and then can do its own stuff, such as presenting another view (i.e RecipeDetail view)